# Intentando hacer que el micrófono esté siempre escuchando (in background) mientras ejecuto otras cosas del programa. Y se encienda una luz si hablo

Tags: python, numpy, sonido

En Ubuntu.
Lo que quiero hacer es que cada vez que el micrófono reciba voz o un ruido superior, la luz se encienda durante ese período.

```
    #Only shows if mic receive sound
    #Solamente muestra si el micrófono recibe sonido
    def lights_on():
        lights=True
```

Este es el código que uso para obtener el volumen del micrófono durante 10 segundos:

```
    import numpy as np
    import sounddevice as sd

    #Look if mic receive sound:
    #Compruebo si el micrófono recibe sonido:
    def comp_sonido():
        duration = 10 #in seconds
        def audio_callback(indata, frames, time, status):
            volume_norm = np.linalg.norm(indata) * 10
            if int(volume_norm)>0:
               lights_on()
        #Uso sounddevice y hago un callback a audio_callback.
        stream = sd.InputStream(callback=audio_callback)
        with stream:
            sd.sleep(duration * 1000)
```

Lo malo es que cuando llamo a la función 'comp_sonido' se bloquea el sistema. No funciona nada incluso pasados los diez segundos y las luces ni siquiera se encienden (si llamo directamente a 'lights_on', sí que funciona, encendiéndose las luces).
Además quiero que esto funcione siempre, no durante diez segundos, y que el programa mientras haga otras cosas.
¿Alguna idea?
¡Gracias!

Comment: probaste usando [hilos(thread)](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/threading.html)

Comment: Disculpa. ¿Podrías ponerme un ejemplo? (si no te importa, claro). Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

¡¡¡ CONSEGUIDO !!!

Efectivamente, como me ha indicado Salvador Mellado, el truco es usar hilos (threads): Este es el código que he empleado:

```
 import aubio
 import numpy as np
 import pyaudio
 import threading
 from tkinter import *

 # Some constants for setting the PyAudio and the
 # Aubio.
  BUFFER_SIZE             = 2048
  CHANNELS                = 1
  FORMAT                  = pyaudio.paFloat32
  METHOD                  = "default"
  SAMPLE_RATE             = 44100
  HOP_SIZE                = BUFFER_SIZE//2
  PERIOD_SIZE_IN_FRAME    = HOP_SIZE

 def main():

     # Initiating PyAudio object.
     pA = pyaudio.PyAudio()
     # Open the microphone stream.
     mic = pA.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
     rate=SAMPLE_RATE, input=True,
     frames_per_buffer=PERIOD_SIZE_IN_FRAME)

     # Initiating Aubio's pitch detection object.
     pDetection = aubio.pitch(METHOD, BUFFER_SIZE,
                  HOP_SIZE, SAMPLE_RATE)
     # Set unit.
     pDetection.set_unit("Hz")
     # Frequency under -40 dB will considered
     # as a silence.
     pDetection.set_silence(-40)

     # Infinite loop!
     while True:
     # Always listening to the microphone.
     data = mic.read(PERIOD_SIZE_IN_FRAME)
     # Convert into number that Aubio understand.
     samples = np.fromstring(data,
               dtype=aubio.float_type)
     # Compute the energy (volume)
     # of the current frame.
     volume = np.sum(samples**2)/len(samples)
     # Format the volume output so it only
     # displays at most six numbers behind 0.
     volume = "{:6f}".format(volume)
     # Only if you want:
     print(volume)
     # turn on the "lights" if volumen > 0.000100 (you can choose your volume)
     if float(volume)>0.000100:
           miframe.config(bg="yellow")
     else:
           miframe.config(bg="red")   
     


if __name__ == "__main__": 
     #Do the window and frame:  
     root=Tk()
     miframe=Frame(root, width=300, height=200, bg="red")
     miframe.pack()
     #Execute main() as THREAD---> daemon:
     threading.Thread(target=main, daemon=True).start()

     root.mainloop()
```

Como podéis ver he cambiado "sounddevice" por "pyaudio". Que a mí me ha funcionado mejor.
Gracias.